# WSO2 IS: What exactly is the sessionId parameter of removeSession in SessionManagementService

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When calling the WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 SessionManagementService the operation removeSession required a sessionId parameter. What exactly is the sessionId in that context (e.g. is it the value stored in a cookie e.g. "commonAuthId").

Background: Can this admin service function be used to terminate a session of a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use this admin service to terminate the session of a user. Here is the method that does it[1].

However a there is a condition,

1. Any user with login permission can call the removeMySession(String sessionId) method and terminate his own session.
2. To terminate the user session of another user, the user calling the admin service should have "/permission/admin/manage/identity/authentication/session/delete" permission.

The sessionId parameter that needs to be sent to [1] is the SHA256 Digest of the commonAuthId cookie value.

That is,

String sessionId = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(commAuthIdCookieValue);
where sessionKey is the value of the commonAuthId cookie.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/70d5fb1e6db5a4bad2e309d8284f559a99e4feb0/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/services/SessionManagementService.java#L36-L36

[2] https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha256Hex(java.lang.String)